# Hide :before and :after pseudo elements if the div has no children

Tags: jquery

The idea is when this specific div is empty, I don't want the pseudo elements to show. (It will obviously be wrapped with the appropriate logic)

I have tried

```
$('.my-feed--adventure').is(':parent') 
$('.my-feed--adventure').children().length > 0
$('.my-feed--adventure:has(div)')
```

but this appears to not suffice, I'm guessing this is because the pseudo elements are acting as children, but I cannot target them, so I am a little stuck.

Any thoughts are welcome.

EDIT:

I should add that the div has no styles, acting as a container so hiding the div works for hiding the pseudo elements in this instance. Question aimed at selecting an empty div that has these pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up using a combination of both of two of the efforts above:

```
if ($('.my-feed--adventure:has(div)').length > 0) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    $('.my-feed--adventure').hide();
}
```

I discovered this mid  way through posting the question, but thought it might be useful for anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cannot be used to target pseudo elements as they are not part of the DOM. The easiest way to remove them without affecting the containing element is via the addition/removal of classes, something like this:

```
#foo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#foo:before {
    content: '';
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #C00;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#foo.no-pseudo:before {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
if ($('.my-feed--adventure').is(':empty')) {
    $(this).addClass('no-pseudo');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the empty selector

`$('.my-feed--adventure:empty').hide();`

This will hide the .my-feed--adventures with no children.

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: While this may be the answer, it is recommended to include documentation and/or explanation in your answer.

Comment: Sadly, empty will not work with pseudo elements as they are considered as "something" in this context.